# Convert points to lines in fsharp

Tags: f#

I have several points that I want to convert to lines. for example `[{x=0; y=0}; {x=1; y=1}; {x=2; y=2}; {x=3; y3}]` should be converted to `[({x=0; y=0}, {x=1; y=1}); ({x=1; y=1}, {x=2; y=2}); ({x=2; y=2}, {x=3; y=3})]`.

my current approach is like this:

```
type Point = { x: int; y: int }

type Line = Point * Point

let rec pointsToLines lines points =
    if (List.length points) < 2 then
        lines
    else
        let line = points.[1], points.[0]
        let lines = line :: lines
        pointsToLines lines (List.tail points)
```

So my question would be, is there one-liner or an idiomatic way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Why the random downvotes? My question is stated in a clear way and shows my attempted solution. If you think there something wrong please state it in the comments section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write it like this for more idiomatic F#:

```
let rec pointsToLines points =
    let rec loop lines points =
        match points with
        | x::y::rest -> loop ((x,y)::lines) rest
        | _ -> lines
    loop [] points
```

However, this already one of the built in functions as you suspected:

```
List.pairwise
```

Both will give you the same results.

Comment: To achieve the same effect of `List.pairwise` I  would change line 4 to be `| x::y::rest -> loop ((x,y)::lines) (y::rest)` and line 6 to be `List.rev (loop [] points)`